# Binding the "Insert" key when running within a terminal

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs

I accidentally hit the insert key so often that I put some code in my .emacs to disable the overwrite-mode key binding:

```
(define-key global-map [(insert)] nil)
(define-key global-map [(control insert)] 'overwrite-mode)
```

This works fine when using emacs within X. However, when I run emacs in the terminal (with -nw or over ssh), insert still turns on overwrite mode.

How can I bind insert in a terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to redefine the key binding for insertchar as opposed to just insert. This means adding

```
(define-key global-map [(insertchar)] nil)
```

to .emacs.

Comment: Note also that `C-h k <insert>` in a terminal would give you the key description `<insertchar>` and therefore you could use `(kbd "<insertchar>")` in your `define-key` call. `C-h k` always gives you a key sequence string that you can plug into `kbd`.